# Different behavior for 1 << 32 compare javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

Javascript

```
1<<31
-2147483648
1<<32
1
```

Python

```
1<<31
2147483648
1<<32
4294967296
```

Is this related to max int?
But 4294967296 not Bigger then the max int in js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: But 4294967296 not bigger then that.

Comment: Quote from the post:  "Note that the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is 2^31-1, or 2147483647."  Did you even read it?

Comment: thanks,I got it,but do you know why 1<<32 using 32bit but 2**32 using 64bit?

Comment: It is part of the design which I don't know why, but this is like asking why JS is not strong typing or why unary operator + will turn string into a number. If you really need to know why, you can open new thread to ask, it is totally different question

Comment: The `**` operator doesn't work only on integers, e.g., `2.25**0.5` is `1.5`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd add that ** isn't a bitwise operator either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer in JavaScript is actually an IEEE 754 64bit float number. But an integer in Python may be a simple integer or a bignum.

---

All bit operations in JavaScript was defined on 32bit signed / unsigned integers. When you do these operations, the two operand was first converted to 32 bit integers, and the result will always be a 32 bit integer.

If you want multiple a number with 2<sup>32</sup>, you should do `1 * 2 ** 32` (or `1 * Math.pow(2, 32)` in ES5) instead of this one.

---

Python has builtin bignum support, which support all bit operations such as shift left. As a result, you may shift a number with any (reasonable) bits and it may be greater than 2<sup>32</sup>.